# Writing a file using Java does not save the file in Mac OSx

Tags: java, macos, file

I am developing a java application in which I need to save some data in a file. I tried to use different methods, however no file gets saved and I don't receive any errors. Here is my code for saving the file:

```
String filename = "/Users/name.txt";
    FileWriter fstream;

    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(filename);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write("My Name is Bobby Bob");
        out.newLine();                                  
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();          
    }
```

I tried even making the file myself but it remains empty.

Comment: No exception thrown? Are you sure your program has permissions to edit the file?

Comment: How should I check for the permissions?

Comment: It should most likely have thrown an exception if that was the case, are you sure nothing happens at all?

Comment: Yes, no errors! My application is on Spring MVC does that help?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` writes the stack trace to `System.err`. Depending how you are running the program you might not see the output. Try using the logging system instead.

Comment: You can check if you have permissions to create the file for example by opening Terminal.app and typing `touch /Users/name.txt`.

Comment: Ok, the problem got solved!!! After cleaning the Tomcat work directory!!! Thanks for the help...

Comment: Well i recommend useing FeleOutPutStream for write file and that will be saved too.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you can write directly to the Users folder through Java on Mac OSX.

Try this to make sure:

```
String filename = "/Users/name.txt";
FileWriter fstream;
try {
    File file = new File(filename);
    // checking if we can write this file
    System.out.println("Can write? " + file.canWrite());
    fstream = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("My Name is Bobby Bob");
    out.newLine();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output expected:

```
Can write? false
```